# How to write a VBA code that will loop through a fixed range and populate each row of that range N times (with numbering) in another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm fairly new to using For Loops and am stuck on getting this code to work - would appreciate any help.

I am trying to write a code that will take a fixed range with two columns (Site and Family combination) and populate it onto another sheet, along with numbering months 1 to 12 in an additional column.

The source data is in the sheet named **LM** and looks like this:

```
Site        Family 
Site1       Family1
Site2       Family2
[...]
```

The outcome should populate in sheet named **MS** and look like this:

```
Site        Family         Month
Site1       Family1        1
Site1       Family1        2
Site1       Family1        3
Site1       Family1        4
Site1       Family1        5
Site1       Family1        6
Site1       Family1        7
Site1       Family1        8
Site1       Family1        9
Site1       Family1        10
Site1       Family1        11
Site1       Family1        12
Site2       Family2        1
Site2       Family2        2
Site2       Family2        3
Site2       Family2        4
Site2       Family2        5
Site2       Family2        6
Site2       Family2        7
Site2       Family2        8
Site2       Family2        9
Site2       Family2        10
Site2       Family2        11
Site2       Family2        12
[...]
```

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub UpdateManualStaging()
    Dim MS As Worksheet, LM As Worksheet
    Dim SiteLM, FamilyLM, SiteMS, FamilyMS
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long
    
    Set LM = Sheets("Lookup & Mapping")
    Set MS = Sheets("Manual Staging")
    
    With LM
    i = .Cells(.rows.count, 23).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
   
    For k = 5 To i
            SiteLM = LM.Cells(k, 23).Value
            FamilyLM = LM.Cells(k, 24).Value
            
        For l = 5 To 17 Step 11
            SiteMS = MS.Cells(l, 3).Value
            FamilyMS = MS.Cells(l, 4).Value
            
            MS.Cells(l, 3).Value = LM.Cells(k, 23).Value
            MS.Cells(l, 4).Value = LM.Cells(k, 24).Value
                
            For m = 1 To 12
                MS.Cells(l, 5).Value = m
            Next m
        Next l
    Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Set LM = Sheets("Lookup & Mapping")
Set MS = Sheets("Manual Staging")
Set strt = LM.Range("w2:x2") 'assumed that the data in sheet LM starts from cell w2 (site) and x2 (family).

Do
Set f = MS.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'assumed that the result in sheet MS starts from cell c2 (site), d2 (family), e2 (month).
f.Offset(0, 2).Value = 1
f.Resize(12, 2).Value = strt.Value
f.Offset(0, 2).AutoFill Destination:=f.Offset(0, 2).Resize(12), Type:=xlFillSeries
Set strt = strt.Offset(1, 0)
Loop Until Application.CountA(strt) = 0

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have formulas on the right in sheet MS (starting from column F), and I want the result to start from C5, D5, E5 instead. The code you suggested populates the result starting from the last row +1 of the already existing data on the right. How could we adjust the code to start from C5 and ignore the existing data with the Rows.Count?

Comment: What did you mean on "starting from the last row +1" ? And what did you mean "ignore the existing data with the Rows.Count" ? The Rows.Count is to get the last row number on the sheet which is 1048576, then the .end(xlup) is to go up until it hit to whatever row which has a value, then the offset(1,0) is to offset 1 row down which of course a blank row. So, say if cell c4,d4,e4 in sheet MS is a header SITE-FAMILY-MONTH and the rest of the rows under it are blank, using the code it will then put the starting result into c5,d5 and e5

Comment: Sorry... I also don't understand "_The code you suggested **populates the result** starting from the last row +1 **of the already existing data on the right**_". How the result overwrite the already existing data in column F while the code put the result on column c,d and e ?

Comment: Sorry, will clarify. Columns C,D and E previously had data, that I cleared  in the first part of my code. I cleared contents only, since I have formulas in columns F that I don't want to break. I believe the .end(xlup) is looking at column C and thinking it is still being used (maybe formatting?) and as a result the data is being copied as of row 365, while my formulas in column F end on row 364.

Comment: _"as a result the data is being copied as of row 365"_ , yes maybe there is something in between C5 to C364 which although the cells look blank (no value), but turns out they are not empty... that's why the code put the result starting from C365. _"I cleared contents only"_, have you tried if you code `.clear` instead of `.clearcontents`, will the formula in column F break ?

Comment: Still not working with the .Clear, but I think it might be due to the fact that the table is a defined named range. So the code will always think cells in columns C,D,E that have an associated  formula in F are filled. I'm going to look into how to consider that! But otherwise your code works perfectly, I just have to figure out how to make it start on C5!

Comment: Is it a table or is it a named range ? If it's a table, then maybe try like this : `LR = MS.ListObjects("TheNameOfTheTable").Range.Rows.Count.....
Range("C" & LR).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select` to see whether the selected cell is C5.